# How to select some specific solumns and also last column in pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas by Python.
I have a DF have the columns: 'id', 'name', 'age', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3',...
If I want to select specific columns, I use `df = df[['name','age']]`, yes, it worked.
But if I want to select specific columns and also the LAST column (in case the last column's name is not static). What should I do?

Comment: As a data is updated every day, a column will be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get last column name by indexing:

```
df = df[['name','age', df.columns[-1]]]
```

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as that. Thanks so much